# Поменять иконку в actionbar menu по клику

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь поделится кодом на смену иконки в ActionBar (menu) по клику на нее (выбрано / не выбрано).

```
<menu
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_favorites_unchecked"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorites_unchecked"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Избранное">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_favorites_checked"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorites_checked"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Избранное">
</item>
</menu>
```

Как это реализовать с помощью:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
```

и

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Таки надо в SharedPreferences завести boolean к вашим кнопкам.

2) В `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` надо найти элементы ваши, проверить значение вышеозначенной переменной и назначить элементам соответственно

> menuItem.setChecked(boolean checked);

3) Ну и сохранить в пресловутую переменную новое значение.

Как-то так.

4) Ну и в XML меню надо прописать, что они выбираемы, элементы эти. Т.е. обернуть их

```
 <group
            android:checkableBehavior="single" >
<!-- тут кнопки -->
</group>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку про group

Comment: Пожалуйста)

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой код получился, может, кому пригодится (не хватает репутации отметить свой ответ как правильный):

```
String name = "Какое-то имя";
boolean addedToFavorites = false; // Не добавлен в избранное

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.ic_favorites_unchecked){
        Toast.makeText(this, name + " добавлен(а) в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, name + " удален(а) из избранного", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    if (!addedToFavorites) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.ic_favorites_checked);
        menu.removeItem(R.id.ic_favorites_checked);
        mi.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_favorites_unchecked);
        mi.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        addedToFavorites = true;

    } else {
        MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.ic_favorites_unchecked);
        menu.removeItem(R.id.ic_favorites_unchecked);
        mi.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_favorites_checked);
        mi.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        addedToFavorites = false;
    }

return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

И сам **XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:checkableBehavior="single" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_favorites_unchecked"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorites_unchecked"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Избранное">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ic_favorites_checked"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_favorites_checked"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Избранное">
</item>

</group>

</menu>
```

Comment: Администраторы, просьба отметить мой собственный ответ как правильный.
Спасибо.